# How to combine and sum a parts of List<T>? C#

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a certain database which consist of many objects, from this database I've got 5 parameters for each object and forming a list:

```
List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, double>> ListOfParts = new List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, double>>();

while (AllParts.MoveNext()) ///where AllParts is the set of all parts, which I've got from database
  {
   foreach (PartClass myPart in AllParts) ///where myPart is the each part of all parts from database
   {
   string GroupName = ///... got it from database
   string ProfileType = ///... got it from database
   string MaterialType = ///... got it from database
   string Profile = ///... got it from database
   double Weight = ///... got it from database
 
   ListOfParts.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string, string, double>(GroupName, ProfileType, MaterialType, Profile, Weight));
   }
  }
 
ListOfParts.Sort();

WriteList(ListOfParts); ///transfer my ListOfParts to another code block

void WriteList(List<Tuple<string, string, string, string, double>> ListOfParts)
 
for (int i = 0; i < ListOfParts.Count; i++)
{
///here is the code to draw a table lines and values of those 5 parameters
}
```

As the result I've got a table like this (Original state):
[image]

Here we can see, that painted cells have similar properties (all of them have ProfileType1, MaterialType1 and Profile2).

I need to combine this rows into one row and sum up their weight as in the following picture (Desired state):
[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you're wanting to sum together... But generally you'd sum properties in a list using `myList.Sum(x => x.propertyToSum)`

Comment: Are you wanting to sum the GroupNameX columns for every row that has matching profile type, material type and profiles?

Comment: I think your question is a fail on 2 languages. SQL and LINQ. I'd export what you need and make it easier on SQL

Comment: At the first stage I need to get rid of recurring rows by "Profile" case, while all other properties are the same. Sorry about my poor knowledge of English.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to sum the groups columns of every row that has matching profile types, material types and profiles.

To make this easier, rather than loading into a list of tuples, I'd create a class to hold your records with a computed property to dictate the matching key that just combines those three fields.

```cs
class MyRecord {
    public string ProfileType  {get; init;}
    public string MaterialType {get; init;}
    public string Profiles     {get; init;}
    
    public int GroupName1 { get; init; }
    //etc

    public string GroupingKey => ProfileType + MaterialType + Profiles;
}
```

Then, we can group by that grouping key and sum the columns you want.

```
List<MyRecord> myRecords = new(); // Load this from the db
var groupedRecords = myRecords.GroupBy(rec => rec.GroupingKey).ToDictionary(rec => rec.Key, rec => rec.ToList());
var group1Results = groupedRecords.Select(r => r.Value.Sum(v => v.GroupName1));
//etc
```

This answers the question as is but probably isn't an optimal solution